# Implicit use of 'self' in closure error when presenting a pop over in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to present a view controller as a pop over if a user successfully resets their password. Basically, if all is ok with emailing a password reset instruction email then the following code will run. However, I am getting the error

**Implicit user of 'self' in closure; use '.self' to make capture semantics explicit**

on the first line  below:

```
    let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResetPasswordSuccessPopOver") as! ResetPasswordSuccessPopOverViewController
    VC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 100)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popover = navController.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.delegate = self

   self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please write full code or explain it well.

Comment: not sure what other code you think it's required to look at the issue. @Anbu.Karthik found my mistake without needing any more code, the rest of my code in this view controller has nothing to do with the pop over and that is why I didn't provide it. Don't understand why so many down votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResetPasswordSuccessPopOver") as ResetPasswordSuccessPopOverViewController
```

or try this

```
  let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResetPasswordSuccessPopOver") as ResetPasswordSuccessPopOverViewController
```

Comment: thanks Anbu! I used your second suggestion. I see my mistake now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift the semantics of self reference being captured are not allowed to be explicit, thus referring to any member of an object inside a closure requires you to show your full commitment to capturing with `self.` being explicitly added to referenced identifiers.

```
let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResetPasswordSuccessPopOver") as! ResetPasswordSuccessPopOverViewController
```

Note `self.` before `storyboard?.`.